# Require character escapes regex

Tags: java, regex

I am attempting to build a key-value serializer and I need to match all characters except `=`, `"`, `,` and `\` when not prefixed with a backslash.

So far what I have to match the rest of the pattern is with 'here' being where I need to match the 'special' characters `^[[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[=][^here]]+$`

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried with an explanation of what does or does not work.

Comment: You can try to use something like this to figure it out yourself: http://txt2re.com/ More people will be willing to help if you put in some effort.

Comment: Can your input have double-backslash which will represent literal? If so how would you like to handle it if it would be before `=`, `"` `,`?

Comment: It looks like you are confusing `[]` with `()`.

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, a double backslash would represent itself.

Comment: I think you are using a wrong approach to the problem. What if a backslash is preceded by another backslash? You should check back on the grammar of the key-value and build regex upon in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern matches all such characters:

```
(?<!\\)[="'\\]
```

In java, the string literal is ugly with all the escapes:

```
String regex = "(?<!\\\\)[=\"'\\\\]";
```